# Custom task picklist doesn't show in active release, but does in definition

Tags: tfs, task

We have a custom task that is exhibiting some strange behavior in our Release flow. One of our inputs is a picklist with 20 options. Additionally, there is a text field that is only visible if you choose the 'Other' option in the picklist. This is the relevant portion of the task.json (with some anonymizing)

```
{
  "name": "Site",
  "type": "picklist",
  "label": "Site Name",
  "defaultValue": "",
  "required": false,
  "helpMarkDown": "Site name - choose 'Other' if desired site is not available",
  "groupName": "GeneralGroup",
  "options": {
    "SITE_1": "SITE_1",
    "SITE_2": "SITE_2",
    "SITE_3": "SITE_3",
    "SITE_4": "SITE_4",
    "SITE_5": "SITE_5",
    "SITE_6": "SITE_6",
    "SITE_7": "SITE_7",
    "SITE_8": "SITE_8",
    "SITE_9": "SITE_9",
    "SITE_10": "SITE_10",
    "SITE_11": "SITE_11",
    "SITE_12": "SITE_12",
    "SITE_13": "SITE_13",
    "SITE_14": "SITE_14",
    "SITE_15": "SITE_15",
    "SITE_16": "SITE_16",
    "SITE_17": "SITE_17",
    "SITE_18": "SITE_18",
    "SITE_19": "SITE_19",
    "Other": "Other"
  }
},
{
  "name": "CustomSite",
  "type": "string",
  "label": "Custom Site Name",
  "defaultValue": "",
  "required": false,
  "helpMarkDown": "Custom site name - if not provided, current site will be used",
  "groupName": "GeneralGroup",
  "visibleRule": "Site = Other"
},
```

The task inputs work great while editing the Release definition, as shown here

Standard site choice
[image]

Other picked
[image]

The issue is when we edit an active release, and look at the task from that view. for some reason, the dropdown does not appear on the screen. A section is available for it, but the dropdown is missing. Another picklist (Environment) displays just fine.

Missing dropdown?
[image]

We're not sure what's going on here, or how to go about resolving it. Other tasks (such as the Nuget) task which have visible rules attached to their picklists don't seem to exhibit this behavior. Any thoughts on what this could be? We are using TFS 2018, update 1, on premises.

Thank you

Edit: Answering questions below

1. I tried creating a brand new release definition from scratch, as well as a brand new build. Within the new release created from the new definition, I continued to see the described behavior
2. Just to clarify, this task is not completely disappearing from the release. Only this one picklist choice is absent when looking at the environments from within an active release.
3. Build definition seems to behave normally. I do not see a way to edit the tasks of a build instance, so I can not confirm if the picklist behave the same as it does in the release instance. However, the build definition itself behaves normally along with the release definition.
4. I did try several page refreshes, along with having a co-worker look from a separate computer. In all cases, this one picklist was not present within the release instance view.

One more thing I looked at, just out of curiosity, is the HTML behind the view. When I compared a picklist that was working vs the problem one, I found that the input control was just completely missing

Working
[image]

Broken
[image]

Edit 2018-06-18:

I've tried many more options and variations of the pick list trying to identify any characteristic that could explain the different behavior between Environment and Site. I tested whether spaces in the label matters, default set/not set, required true/false, underscores we had in the pick list values, various lengths of the pick list (everything from 5 items to 20), and removing apostrophes from the help text. Almost at a loss on what to try next...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many trials and errors, I found the answer glaring in my face

```
  "type": "picklist",
```

is wrong

```
  "type": "pickList",
```

is right. TFS seems to accept both, and both render correctly on the Release and Build definition screens, however only `pickList` (capital L) will render properly on the release instance screen.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you first test with a newly add release if it works well. This will narrow down if the issue just related to that specific release.

Also open and close, reopen that specific release. If it should be an intermittent issue, refresh should fix it.

Besides, suggest you also go through the history of your release definition, if there   have unexpected edits. If something is causing a change to the definition, it should show there as an update and might provide some clues as to why these tasks disappearing.

Then also check if these custom tasks are also missing the picklist in corresponding build definition.

One possibility,  the task with this picklist is developed after the active released created. So the changes could not be synchronized. In this case, you could create a totally new release and include this task. This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I've answered your questions and provided some additional information in the Edit at the bottom of the question.

Comment: A colleague and I are suspecting it may be related to the number of items in the picklist. The broken one has 20 items in it, while the other has only 5. We are creating a version of the task with many picklists of various lengths in it to see if that supplies any new information. Will update when I have more!

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I did eventually work out the answer in that I had a slight typo in my input type which caused the inconsistent behavior we noticed.

Comment: @TylerLee Thanks for the sharing, glad to hear the issue fixed. Always better when you fix it yourself; as you understand how it works! :)